# csvを読み込みモラン散布図を作成したいが手順が分からない。

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, 地理情報

csvデータをもとに、モラン散布図を作成したいのですが、データを読み込みそこから何をすればモラン散布図が作れるのか理解ができていない。しなければいけない手順やコードとそのコードの意味を教えてほしい。

Comment: 「モラン散布図を作成したいが手順が分からない。」というのは、手計算はできるがRでの作成方法が分からない、という意味でしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。手計算も理解できていない状態となっております。

Comment: 検索するとこんな記事が関係ありそうですが。[「Rではじめる地理空間データの統計解析入門」を衛星データを使って実践](https://qiita.com/chicken_data_analyst/items/6a8a6491fd0c4d12e665), [3-3_母子世帯の空間クラスター](https://rpubs.com/jirei_de_gis/c_a_2_3_3)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。提示してもらった文献を拝見しているのですが、そのコードをどのように自分のデータでも適用するようにアレンジすればよいかが分かっておらず困っている状態です。

Comment: どのような分野のデータであるとか、CSVファイルのフォーマットや内容(抜粋でも)、そしてそれらデータのどれを図にしたいか、そして今の所どのくらいまで処理やプログラムが出来ているか、そして分からないことの最初の部分は何処かといったことを整理してなるべく詳細にテキストで追記してみてください。具体的な情報が無くて困っているというだけでは助言・回答を得ることは難しいでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。具体的にいうことが大切でした。助言ありがとうございます。私が図にしたいデータはある都道府県の市町村別の職種や土地利用状況が書かれているcsvファイルです。そしてこれらを作るためには空間重み行列を作る必要があります。そしてこれを作るためには近隣リストを作る必要があります。近隣リストは私が対象にしているシェープファイルから作る必要があるのですが、そのやり方がまずはわかっていません。

Comment: 先ほどのコメントに追記です。①私の持っているデータ【シェープファイル、csvファイル】から近隣リストを作りたい②近隣リストから空間重み行列を作りたい③モラン散布図の作成　という順序なのですが、有識者の方がおられましたらコメントしていただけると幸いです。

Comment: https://web.sfc.keio.ac.jp/~maunz/ESTRELA/200909_74.pdfこちらのコードを打てば自作できると思うのですが、それを私のデータに適用するにはどのようなコードを打てばいいのかがわからない状況です。

Answer (score 0):

紛らわしくしてすみません。R言語でのモラン統計量の情報がありました。3-2.のところです。

[「空間相関」の考え方を整理してみた。](https://qiita.com/purple_jp/items/13c9ec6b45e26b555978)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。そちらを参考にしているのですが、うまくいかないところが多く壁にぶつかっています。

Comment: うまくいかないことを提示しないと、回答できないと思います。

Comment: shpファイルとcsvファイルをテーブル結合したデータから近隣リストを作り空間重み行列を作りたいのですが、「'path' 引数が不正です 。」と出てしまいます。これの対処法がわかる方はおられますでしょうか。

Comment: 状況は不確かですがアウトプットのデータが上手く出来ていないと思います。csvのファイルでアウトプットするならその前のコードが上手く出来ていないと思います。